# A simple algorithm for polygon intersection

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, polygon

I'm looking for a very simple algorithm for computing the polygon intersection/clipping.
That is, given polygons `P`, `Q`, I wish to find polygon `T` which is contained in `P` and in `Q`, and I wish `T` to be maximal among all possible polygons.

I don't mind the run time (I have a few very small polygons), I can also afford getting an approximation of the polygons' intersection (that is, a polygon with less points, but which is still contained in the polygons' intersection).

But it is really important for me that the algorithm will be simple (cheaper testing) and preferably short (less code).

**edit:** please note, I wish to obtain a polygon which represent the intersection. I don't need only a boolean answer to the question of whether the two polygons intersect.

Comment: Are polygons convex or not? Because if not, then their intersection will not be necessary one polygon.

Comment: @DNNX, If they were convex that would be easy. They aren't convex, and I'm interested with finding all the polygons which represents the intersection.

Comment: Did you look at this question?  Yours is not quite the same, since you are asking about simplicity of implementation.  But some of the libraries mentioned might do what you need...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526352/how-to-intersect-two-polygons

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I understand the original poster was looking for a simple solution, but unfortunately there really is no simple solution.

Nevertheless, I've recently created an open-source freeware clipping library (written in Delphi, C++ and C#) which clips all kinds of polygons (including self-intersecting ones). This library is pretty simple to use: https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Clipper2

Comment: I came to this unfortunate conclusion myself not long ago. Every solution is agonizingly complex. Thanks for the library!

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that my Clipper library also compares very favorably with other clipping libraries: http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php#features

Comment: @angus johnson what would you use for simple testing if a polygon interects with another or if its fully contained?

Comment: @AngusJohnson, does your library support calculate two open path's intersection points? thanks

Comment: Update from 2018: Polyclipping has been renamed *Clipper* and is available as a NuGet package.

Comment: Hello @AngusJohnson, Is there an algorithm for clipping a polygon with polyline? I am trying to find a way to clip a  polygon with polyline.

Answer (score 21):

You could use a **Polygon Clipping** algorithm to find the intersection between two polygons.  However these tend to be complicated algorithms when all of the edge cases are taken into account.

One implementation of polygon clipping that you can use your favorite search engine to look for is **Weiler-Atherton**. [wikipedia article on Weiler-Atherton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler-Atherton_clipping_algorithm)

Alan Murta has a complete implementation of a polygon clipper [GPC](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/gpc.html).

Edit:

Another approach is to first divide each polygon into a set of triangles, which are easier to deal with. The **Two-Ears Theorem** by Gary H. Meisters does the trick. This [page at McGill](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Ian/twoears.html) does a good job of explaining triangle subdivision.

Comment: I googled for polygon clipping, and found those results as well. However, please note that these algorithms are meant to be efficient exact and complex. I'm aiming for a slow, possibly approximated algorithm which is SIMPLE.

Comment: I too wish there were a simple to use method.  One would imagine that WPF and GDI+ do the sort of clipping that would be generally useful if the more primitive geometry operations were exposed through the API.

When one starts simple, the program grows more complex over time as those difficult edge cases are taken into account.

Answer (score 15):

If you use C++, and don't want to create the algorithm yourself, you can use [Boost.Geometry](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl). It uses an adapted version of the Weiler-Atherton algorithm mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

You have not given us your representation of a polygon. So I am choosing (more like suggesting) one for you :)

Represent each polygon as one big convex polygon, and a list of smaller convex polygons which need to be 'subtracted' from that big convex polygon.

Now given two polygons in that representation, you can compute the intersection as:

Compute intersection of the big convex polygons to form the big polygon of the intersection. Then 'subtract' the intersections of all the smaller ones of both to get a list of subracted polygons.

You get a new polygon following the same representation.

Since convex polygon intersection is easy, this intersection finding should be easy too.

This seems like it should work, but I haven't given it more deeper thought as regards to correctness/time/space complexity.

Comment: Wow! This is *just* what I had in mind, but: (1) the polygons are represented as series of CW segments, and converting it to convex-convex is nontrivial. (2) After substructing the first convex, I get a nonconvex shape I need to handle, and I'm not sure that substructing a convex from a polygon is much easier than finding the intersection between two polygons...

Comment: @Elazar: To convert line segement representation to Convex - Convex, you can do the following: 1) Form the convex hull. 2) For each side of the convex hull, if it is not inside, you can find a non-convex polygon you need to subtract. You can then 'triangulate' this non-convex polygon to get a union of convex shapes. As to your point 2): you don't actually have to do any actual subtracting if you work with that representation. I suppose for the convex hull + 'triangulation', there will be packages to do that already.

Comment: This algorithm would fail on the "pitchfork blades instersecting at right angles" example in the following comment.  Specifically, it would miss the cutouts it should add next to the crossbar of each pitchfork.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm needs to subtract all the smaller polygons of both shapes, not their intersections. You might want to intersect them with the new hull, though.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple-and-stupid approach: on input, discretize your polygons into a bitmap. To intersect, AND the bitmaps together. To produce output polygons, trace out the jaggy borders of the bitmap and smooth the jaggies using a [polygon-approximation algorithm](http://www.jarno.demon.nl/polygon.htm). (I don't remember if that link gives the most suitable algorithms, it's just the first Google hit. You might check out one of the tools out there to convert bitmap images to vector representations. Maybe you could call on them without reimplementing the algorithm?)

The most complex part would be [tracing out the borders](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/29/an-alternate-way-to-implement-marching-ants/), I think.

Back in the early 90s I faced something like this problem at work, by the way. I muffed it: I came up with a (completely different) algorithm that would work on real-number coordinates, but seemed to run into a completely unfixable plethora of degenerate cases in the face of the realities of floating-point (and noisy input). Perhaps with the help of the internet I'd have done better!

Comment: Tracing the borders might be easier if you realize that each vertex will either be the vertex of one of the polygons, or an intersection of a line segment from each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have no very simple solution, but here are the main steps for the *real* algorithm:

1. Do a **custom** double linked list for the polygon vertices and
   edges. Using `std::list` won't do because you must swap next and
   previous pointers/offsets yourself for a special operation on the
   nodes. This is the only way to have simple code, and this will give
   good performance.
2. Find the intersection points by comparing each pair of edges. Note
   that comparing each pair of edge will give O(N²) time, but improving
   the algorithm to O(N·logN) will be easy afterwards. For some pair of
   edges (say a→b and c→d), the intersection point is found by using
   the parameter (from 0 to 1) on edge a→b, which is given by
   tₐ=d₀/(d₀-d₁), where d₀ is (c-a)×(b-a) and d₁ is (d-a)×(b-a). × is
   the 2D cross product such as p×q=pₓ·qᵧ-pᵧ·qₓ. After having found tₐ,
   finding the intersection point is using it as a linear interpolation
   parameter on segment a→b: P=a+tₐ(b-a)
3. Split each edge adding vertices (and nodes in your linked list)
   where the segments intersect.
4. Then you must *cross* the nodes at the intersection points. This is
   the operation for which you needed to do a custom double linked
   list. You must swap some pair of *next* pointers (and update the
   *previous* pointers accordingly).

Then you have the raw result of the polygon intersection resolving algorithm. Normally, you will want to select some region according to the winding number of each region. Search for **polygon winding number** for an explanation on this.

If you want to make a O(N·logN) algorithm out of this O(N²) one, you must do exactly the same thing except that you do it inside of a line sweep algorithm. Look for **Bentley Ottman algorithm**. The inner algorithm will be the same, with the only difference that you will have a reduced number of edges to compare, inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked about the same problem

1. breaking the polygon into line segments
2. find intersecting line using `IntervalTrees` or `LineSweepAlgo`
3. finding a closed path using `GrahamScanAlgo` to find a closed path with adjacent vertices
4. Cross Reference 3. with `DinicAlgo` to Dissolve them

note: my scenario was different given the polygons had a common vertice. But Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about predictable run time you could try by first splitting your polygons into unions of convex polygons and then pairwise computing the intersection between the sub-polygons.

This would give you a collection of convex polygons such that their union is exactly the intersection of your starting polygons.

Answer (score 0):

If the polygons are not aligned then they have to be aligned. I would do this by finding the centre of the polygon (average in X, average in Y) then incrementally rotating the polygon by matrix transformation, project the points to one of the axes and use the angle of minimum stdev to align the shapes (you could also use principal components). For finding the intersection, a simple algorithm would be define a grid of points. For each point maintain a count of points inside one polygon, or the other polygon or both (union) (there are simple & fast algorithms for this eg. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=PolyContainsPoint). Count the points polygon1 & polygon2, divide by the amount of points in polygon1 or Polygon2 and you have a rough (depending on the grid sampling) estimate of proportion of polygons overlap. The intersection area would be given by the points corresponding to an AND operation.

eg.

```
function get_polygon_intersection($arr, $user_array)
{
    $maxx = -999;  // choose sensible limits for your application
    $maxy = -999;
    $minx = 999;
    $miny = 999;
    $intersection_count = 0;
    $not_intersected = 0;
    $sampling = 20;
    
    // find min, max values of polygon (min/max variables passed as reference)
    get_array_extent($arr, $maxx, $maxy, $minx, $miny);
    get_array_extent($user_array, $maxx, $maxy, $minx, $miny);
    
    $inc_x = $maxx-$minx/$sampling;
    $inc_y = $maxy-$miny/$sampling;
    
    // see if x,y is within poly1 and poly2 and count
    for($i=$minx; $i<=$maxx; $i+= $inc_x)
    {
        for($j=$miny; $j<=$maxy; $j+= $inc_y)
        {
            $in_arr = pt_in_poly_array($arr, $i, $j);
            $in_user_arr = pt_in_poly_array($user_array, $i, $j);
            
            if($in_arr && $in_user_arr)
            {
                $intersection_count++;
            }
            else
            {
                $not_intersected++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // return score as percentage intersection
    return 100.0 * $intersection_count/($not_intersected+$intersection_count);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be a huge approximation depending on your polygons, but here's one :

- Compute the center of mass for each
  polygon.
- Compute the min or max or average
  distance from each point of the
  polygon to the center of mass.
- If C1C2 (where C1/2 is the center of the first/second polygon) >= D1 + D2 (where D1/2 is the distance you computed for first/second polygon) then the two polygons "intersect".

Though, this should be very efficient as any transformation to the polygon applies in the very same way to the center of mass and the center-node distances can be computed only once.

Comment: And how to I get a polygon representing the intersection area?