# Good algorithm for determination of non convex 2D figures collision

Tags: algorithm, math, 2d, collision-detection, non-convex

could you please provide me with some information (or suggest an article) on good collision detection algorithm for 2D non convex figures?

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: Do you need a simple *Do they intersect?* answer or do you need the intersection?

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: I need simple "do they intersect" answer.

Comment: I added an answer for simple polygons. It *may* help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Try this:


http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/


Note that it isn't free for commercial use.</del>

For more details you can continue to this similar question:

[A simple algorithm for polygon intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection)

---

**To determine if two [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Convexity) polygons intersect :**

If two simple polygons have a non-void intersection then one of the following will happen:

A) One of them has a corner inside the interior of the other one.
B) One of them has a whole edge inside the interior of the other one (the corners of that edge may not necessarily be in the interior). This means the middle of that edge will be inside the interior.
C) The polygons are identical.
D) There are two edges that intersect at an angle. The intersection point not being a corner to any of the polygons.

What you need to do is check if the polygons are identical (have the same corners), or one of the corners or one of the middle of the edges lies inside the interior of the other polygon or if there are two edges that intersect somewhere else than in a corner.

[Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon.](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/insidepoly/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need an algorithm, not a library.

Comment: I don't think you covered all case. Consider: http://i.imgur.com/NbCyp.png It might be correct if B) is changed to if any two edges intersect.

Comment: @job With B) I had something else in mind and I think it should be kept. Maybe adding a *D) There are two edges that intersect at an angle*.

Answer (score 1):

I always found the wikipedia pages to be quite useful for my needs:

[Sutherland Hodgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm)

[Liang Barsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liang%E2%80%93Barsky)

[Weiler Atherton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton)

As well as [this paper](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Classes/CS430/HWs/p214-weiler.pdf) on the Weiler Atherton algorithm.