# Designate intersections of polygons

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of polygons on a plane given as a series of points. Polygons can intersect with each other.

How can I find all intersections which belongs to at least two polygons?

Which algorithms can be useful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection of polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223849/intersection-of-polygons)

Comment: First you do some research, then you make an attempt.  If you're stuck, post your attempt here and someone can help you.  It's not that hard to google either....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection

Comment: [oldie course](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep521/01au/lectures/lecture10slides.pdf)