# Clipper how to get all polygons connected to a given points

Tags: c#, geometry, vector-graphics, clipperlib

I'm currently working on a project where I have to find all points connected to a given set of coordinates in a set of clipper polygons. So that means that I have the following:

```
    List<List<IntPoint>> polygons=new List<List<IntPoint>>();
    IntPoint start
```

and would like to have a return value of List> containing every polygon that has an uninterupted connected towards start.

```
 __   __ 
| /   \/
|/

1,1
```

would change into

```
    __
   | /
   |/
```

But

```
_____ 
| /_/
|/
1,1
```

would remain unganged

The polygons are all closed, some may overlap.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I know this might not be the clearest of questions but it's hard to improve so if you want me to explain anything leave a comment!

Comment: Look here for polygon intersection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection

Comment: To echo Roman, you want to examine algorithms for Boolean operations on polygons, e.g., at this [MathOverflow answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/111323/6094).