# Get intersection size of two geometries

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I've got some funky xml files containing closed complex 2d geometric forms (these represent owned property). I want to read these xml geometries into PathGeometry / PathFigures.

How do I get the cut surface between two of these PathGeometries?
And is there a way to get the size of the cut surface (e.g. in relation to the full size of one of the geometries).

Or should I rather use something else instead of PathGeometry to get the cross section?

Comment: Might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526352/how-to-intersect-two-polygons

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than I would have thought:

```
PathGeometry firstGeometry;
PathGeometry secondGeometry;
PathGeometry intersectionGeometry = PathGeometry.Combine(firstGeometry, secondGeometry, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);
```